# Hide index bar when searching UITableView

Tags: ios, xcode, indexing, uisearchbar

I  have implemented a search bar and index capability for my table view. Working well. However, I noticed that when I click in the search bar, the index is still available and clicking on it causes unpredictable results. Rather than debug that, I thought it would be simpler to hide the index :)

I found references elsewhere to calling `sectionIndexTitlesForSectionView` and returning nil. So, when I click in the search box, in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing` I have made an explicit call to `[self sectionIndexTitlesForSectionView:[self tableView]]`.

The result is that `sectionIndexTitlesForSectionView` does get invoked and return nil, but the index is still present.

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
Tony.

Comment: Still hoping someone can help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 25):

You have to return nil in `- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` if you the search is active, as you note in your post. Then, override two methods from the `UISearchDisplayDelegate` to refresh the indices.

```
- (void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}

- (void)searchDisplayControllerDidEndSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller {
    [self.tableView reloadSectionIndexTitles];
}
```

For the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` method, I prefer to use:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (self.searchDisplayController.active) {
        return nil;
    } else {
        //Add @"{search}", to beginning to add search icon to top of index
        return @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J", @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T", @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", @"#"];
    }
}
```

NOTE: I found that you must use `self.searchDisplayController.active`in the if condition. It doesn't work if you use `tableView != self.tableView`.

Answer (score 0):

Simply have the method `(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView` return `nil` when you are displaying the search results.

In my case, this looks something like this:

```
- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    if (tableView == [self tableView]) {
        return [[NSArray arrayWithObject:UITableViewIndexSearch] arrayByAddingObjectsFromArray:[collation sectionIndexTitles]];
    }
    // search view, no index:
    else return nil;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Marcel. Maybe I wasn't clear enough - I too am returning nil - I have confirmed in the debugger that nil is being returned from this function - however, the index is still displayed.

Comment: Then I think I don't understand the problem well. Probably best if you'd post some code.

Comment: Here's the code: 

`- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView

{
    
    // if searching, no need to display the index
    if (isSearchOn)
        return nil;
    else
    {
        // make sure index doesn't overlap the search bar input field
        [(id)searchBar setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 0, 5, 35)];
        
        return englishIndex;
    }
}`

Comment: I commented in the wrong place. Pls see above for more legible code :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way, if you don't want to pass nil in sectionIndexTitlesForTableView, If you have to make only one index for search text and want to show  search text as section header title.

```
NSArray *subViewsOfTblView = [self.tableView subviews];
if([subViewsOfTblView count] > 0)
{
    UIView *indexVw = (UIView*)subViewsOfTblView[[subViewsOfTblView count] - 1];
    if(isSearchON || isFilterON)
        indexVw.hidden = YES;
    else
        indexVw.hidden = NO;
}
```